# Hibernate connection with HSQLDB

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, hsqldb

I have a problem while setting up my first Hibernate project. I follow the tutorial and get stuck when I launch my code. What happens is that the program get stuck, I believe, when starting the connection with HSQLDB. It does not provide any error message.
The verbose output in the console is the following:

```
172 [main] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
172 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
172 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
187 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
187 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
265 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
265 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
375 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Reading mappings from resource : org/itg/ACLwithHibernate/User.hbm.xml
484 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configured SessionFactory: null
```

now it is configured, I call buildSessionFactory():

```
562 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder - Mapping class: org.itg.ACLwithHibernate.User -> USER
577 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
593 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
593 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
593 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 10
593 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - autocommit mode: false
609 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - using driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver at URL: jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001
609 [main] INFO org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider - connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
```

and... nothing more. It never goes on to the next instructions in my main() class. It is stuck somewhere.
When I debug, I get this:

[overview of the debugger](http://s7.postimage.org/51xzluq3t/debug_Hibernate.png)

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9001</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping resource="org/itg/ACLwithHibernate/User.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My HSQLDB server is running and outputed the following:

```
[Server@3ed5dee4]: [Thread[org.hsqldb.Server.main(),5,org.hsqldb.Server]]: checkRunning(false) entered
[Server@3ed5dee4]: [Thread[org.hsqldb.Server.main(),5,org.hsqldb.Server]]: checkRunning(false) exited
[Server@3ed5dee4]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
[Server@3ed5dee4]: Loaded properties from [C:\Users\dbr\workspace\test_hibernate\server.properties]
[Server@3ed5dee4]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@3ed5dee4]: Server socket opened successfully in 0 ms.
[Server@3ed5dee4]: Database [index=0, id=0, db=file:target/data/tutorial, alias=] opened sucessfully in 630 ms.
[Server@3ed5dee4]: Startup sequence completed in 640 ms.
[Server@3ed5dee4]: 2012-07-18 12:36:53.717 HSQLDB server 2.0.0 is online on port 9001
[Server@3ed5dee4]: To close normally, connect and execute SHUTDOWN SQL
[Server@3ed5dee4]: From command line, use [Ctrl]+[C] to abort abruptly
```

When server.silent = false, I get in addition the following when my client connects:

```
[Thread[HSQLDB Server @1af5458a,5,org.hsqldb.Server]]: handleConnection(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=49438,localport=9001]) entered
[Thread[HSQLDB Server @1af5458a,5,org.hsqldb.Server]]: handleConnection() exited
[Thread[HSQLDB Connection @9437a04,5,HSQLDB Connections @1af5458a]]: ODBC client connected.  ODBC Protocol Compatibility Version 0.0
```

Have you encountered a similar issue before? Do you have an idea about what is going wrong?
Thank you very much in advance.
Dany

Comment: Is your database running on localhost? Can you telnet to localhost:9001?

Comment: @Funtik You are right, I didn't think about trying that. Yes, I can telnet and I get `HSQLDB JDBC Network Listener. User JDBC driver with Network Compatibility Version1.9.0.0 and a JDBC URL like jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://hostname...` then the connection is dropped.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the HSQLDB, but I would try to create a database alias, and use it as a DB name in hibernate connection

Comment: To debug, add server.silent=false to server.properties. Try with HSQLDB 2.2.8 (from Maven) as this is more compatible with the Hibernate dialect.

Comment: Thank you @fredt, I tried with version 2.2.8 & server.silent=false and I edited my post to include the inherent logs.

Comment: The server message should not say ODBC client. Therefore you are propbably using different HSQLDB jars for your program and the server. Make sure the same 2.2.8 jar is used and verify the server is reporting "HSQLDB server 2.2.8 server is online .." and not saying ODBC when a connection is made.

Comment: @fredt: it WORKED! So it was a version problem... Thank you. Please submit it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an HSQLDB Server is used with Hibernate or other frameworks, it is essential to check the HSQLDB jar version used by the client and server and make sure they are both the same version of HSQLDB. It is also necessary to use an up-to-date version of HSQLDB.

It is easy to troubleshoot an HSQLDB Server if you start it with the property `server.silent=false` (or `silent=false` as a command line argument). This will show the attempted connections.

In this example, the server is showing:

```
[Thread[HSQLDB Connection @9437a04,5,HSQLDB Connections @1af5458a]]: 
      ODBC client connected.  ODBC Protocol Compatibility Version 0.0
```

which indicates a version incompatibility problem, as the ODBC is not actually used for Java to HSQLDB connections.

Answer (score 0):

It stuck in connecting to your DB.
for debugging remove the connection pool size element from the configuration and set hbmtoddl to false.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gives me the very same behavior and output. Somehow, the connection seems to be established well, because when I terminate the 'frozen' code I get a `java.net.SocketException: Connection reset` on the ouput of my server.

Comment: I have though `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=debug`, `log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout` and `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug` in my log4j.properties.

Comment: but you run in info mode and not debug mode. you can see that log level is info