# Hibernate configuration file for HSQLDB database server

Tags: hibernate, web-services, configuration, hsqldb, configuration-files

I am new in hibernate programming and I do not know how to write hibernate configuration file for HSQLDB database server. The server is on the local host.

- username is: michael
- password is: jane$%12#

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540758/hibernate-connection-with-hsqldb) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0350__Hibernate/HibernateandHSQL.htm)

Comment: Try this [link](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-tools-1.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">michael</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">jane$%12#</property>    
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping resource="yourclassname.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```